# Freerouting unable to route

Tags: pcb, kicad

I am trying to route the PCB I designed in KiCad with Freerouting's autoroute feature, but have noticed that it seems to be unable to route one of my LGA-12 ICs (U2 on the board shown below). What are some of the things I should look out for to prevent this?

**KiCad PCB Layout:**

[image]

**FreeRouting fails to route U2**

[image]

Comment: I won't say there is never a time to use an autorouter, but this is definitely not one of them. In this situation you should route the traces yourself and not expect an autorouter to do it for you.

Comment: Don't autoroute something as simple as this, but I think that there must be better autorouters out there. I don't expect intel to hand route their latest chip and the compilation of code into a FPGA is effectively autorouting.

Comment: Down the bottom right quarter you have two tracks running parallel on different layers right next to your no-go area. That makes a pretty much impassable barrier for more tracks to be added.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll just manually route.

Comment: Autorouting is rarely worth it, and most definitely isn't worth it for this as others have pointed out. There are very, very few situations where I would even consider using an autorouter and even then they require a lot of rules and setup to make them work. They were never intended to be a "just press this button and walk away with a perfectly designed board." They are designed to accomplish specific tasks in specific applications